# How can I manipulate the position of my <a> tags so they go where I want in my <li> tags?

Tags: html, css

The  tags are sitting outside the areas of the `<li>` tag that I want them in. I want the  tags centered in the grey areas with a lot of padding so they can be used like buttons. I had to mess with some things to get the buttons responsive and that resulted in the messed up positioning.

I tried messing with the position: ; attributes because I think that's what caused things to go haywire, also tried changing the display: ; attributes.

```css
main div ul.primary-list {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: .5% 1fr 1fr .5%;
  grid-template-rows: 50% 50%;
  grid-template-areas: ". bathroom bedrooom ."". kitchen livingroom .";
}

main div ul.primary-list li#bathroom-button {
  grid-area: bathroom;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #d1d1d1;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-top-left-radius: 300px;
}

main div ul.primary-list li#bathroom-button:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
}

main div ul.primary-list li#bathroom-button a {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
}

main div ul.primary-list li#bedroom-button {
  text-align: center;
  grid-area: bedrooom;
  background-color: #d1d1d1;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  border-top-right-radius: 300px;
}

main div ul.primary-list li#bedroom-button:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
}

main div ul.primary-list li#bedroom-button a {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
}

main div ul.primary-list li#kitchen-button {
  text-align: center;
  grid-area: kitchen;
  background-color: #d1d1d1;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 300px;
}

main div ul.primary-list li#kitchen-button:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
}

main div ul.primary-list li#kitchen-button a {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
}

main div ul.primary-list li#livingroom-button {
  text-align: center;
  grid-area: livingroom;
  background-color: #d1d1d1;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 300px;
}

main div ul.primary-list li#livingroom-button:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
}

main div ul.primary-list li#livingroom-button a {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <div>
      <h1>The Essential List</h1>
    </div>

  </header>
  <main>
    <h2>Pick an area</h2>

    <div>

      <ul class="primary-list">
        <li id="bathroom-button"><a href="#">Bathroom</a></li>
        <li id="bedroom-button"><a>Bedroom</a></li>
        <li id="kitchen-button"><a>Kitchen</a></li>
        <li id="livingroom-button"><a>Living Room</a></li>
      </ul>

    </div>

  </main>
  <footer>

    <div>
      <p>Somethingsomethingsomething</p>
    </div>

  </footer>

  <script>
  </script>
</body>
```

I was *hoping* the `<a>` tags would continue to be nested in the middle of my `<li>` tags, but they seem to be sitting in the top left corner.

Comment: can you add image of what you want that li should be ?

Answer (score 0):

So, to your `<a></a>` style add width and height to auto so you could position them with this:

```
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
transform: translate(50%,-50%);
```

it will be centered, then you can add padding to a as well.

Other option is to set width and height to 100%, then set:

```
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
line-height: 100%;
```

but this will prevent adding padding unless you add some selector inside `<a></a>`

Comment: That first solution worked really well getting the <a></a> centered! However, adding any amount of padding seems to push the <a> tags to the right. The more padding, the further right they go. Do i need to correct this somehow? Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, your right add this to your "transform:translate(calc(-50% + 30px), calc(-50% + 30px));" 30px is a size of padding, change it to your needs.